# Using the lag function with two different columns R

Tags: r, dplyr, lag

I have data such as this.

```
data.input <-read_table2("user.id   problem.id  first.correct   cwa_prob    prob.seq    
540995  PRABNBZQ    0   1   problem.id.problem.1    
540995  PRABNBZ2    1   0   problem.id.problem.2    
540995  PRABNBZK    0   1   problem.id.problem.3    
540995  PRABNB2B    0   1   problem.id.problem.4    
540995  PRABNBWE    0   1   problem.id.problem.5    
565662  PRABNB2B    1   0   problem.id.problem.1    
565662  PRABNBZQ    1   1   problem.id.problem.2    
565662  PRABNBZ9    1   0   problem.id.problem.3    
565662  PRABNBZV    1   0   problem.id.problem.4    
565662  PRABNBWG    1   0   problem.id.problem.5    
")
```

I am trying to use the lag function to compare the occurrence of a flag in two separate columns. I want to see how a person fairs sequentially from one problem to the next. Specifically, if `cwa_prob` is `1` for `problem.id.problem.1` (user `540995`), is it the case that `first.correct==1` in `problem.id.problem.2` (user `540995`).

I tried something like this, but it throws me an error.

```
input.data %>% 
  group_by(user.id) %>% 
  mutate(post.cwa.correct=ifelse(cwa_prob==1 & lag(first.correct==1),1,0))
```

I would like my output to look something like this:

```
data.output <-read_table2("user.id  problem.id  first.correct   cwa_prob    prob.seq    post.cwa.correct
540995  PRABNBZQ    0   1   problem.id.problem.1    NA
540995  PRABNBZ2    1   0   problem.id.problem.2    1
540995  PRABNBZK    0   1   problem.id.problem.3    NA
540995  PRABNB2B    0   1   problem.id.problem.4    0
540995  PRABNBWE    0   1   problem.id.problem.5    0
565662  PRABNB2B    1   0   problem.id.problem.1    1
565662  PRABNBZQ    1   1   problem.id.problem.2    NA
565662  PRABNBZ9    1   0   problem.id.problem.3    1
565662  PRABNBZV    1   0   problem.id.problem.4    NA
565662  PRABNBWG    1   0   problem.id.problem.5    NA
")
```

Maybe the lag function isn't the best function for this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description I think this is what you want :

```
library(dplyr)

data.input %>%
  group_by(user.id) %>%
  mutate(post.cwa.correct = as.integer(first.correct == 1 & lag(cwa_prob) == 1))
```

This will give a value of 1 when the current row has `first.correct = 1` and the previous row has `cwa_prob = 1` .

Note that you don't need `ifelse(condition, 1, 0)` since you can convert `TRUE`/`FALSE` values to 1/0 by converting them to integer. Also in your attempt you have `lag(first.correct==1)` which is different from `lag(first.correct) ==1`.

Comment: This is brilliant @Ronak Shah. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran everything, and it worked fine. However the output you list as wanted doesn't actually meet your criteria...you'd want

```
data.input %>% 
  group_by(user.id) %>% 
  mutate(post.cwa.correct=ifelse(cwa_prob==0, NA, ifelse(
    cwa_prob==1 & lead(first.correct==1),1,0)
  ))
```

However, you list the dataset as "data.input," but then the dataset you use is listed as "input.data."

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `lag` documentation. There is an `order_by` argument that determines the sort order of your records.

Unless you sent this argument, R uses the existing/default order for your dataset. So different ordering will produce different answers. This is a likely explanation for why your code has not worked, but @James founds that the code ran fine.

```r
input.data %>% 
  group_by(user.id) %>% 
  mutate(post.cwa.correct=ifelse(cwa_prob==1 & lag(first.correct==1, order_by = "prob.seq"),1,0))
```

Note that as the format of `prob_seq` is most likely character, the `order_by` clause will sort alphabetically. This means `'problem.10'` will come before `'problem.2'`. So you'll need to extract and convert the problem number to numeric if this occurs in your data.